# Forwarding Nginx port to gunicorn instance

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I was following this tutorial to setup my flask server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-securing-the-application

When I got to step 6 I see that they are setting flask for the whole url but I would like to point it to a specific port.

This is the code I have for my nginx which points. This currenly produces a 404.

```
server {
        listen 5000;
        server_name site.com;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
        }
}
```

All the other files are the same as the tutorial. I have tried to modify the .sock file but it seems like it was generated automatically and it can't be modified. In addition I need to find a way for nginx to handle this before I worry about handling it from gunicorn.

My end goal is to have nginx foward requests to flask running when a request is sent to `0.0.0.0:5000` and have all other requests `0.0.0.0 , 0.0.0.0/*` be handled by nginx.

Any help to undestand all this is really appreciated got lost at this point.

**EDIT**

my nginx configuration in sites-available

```
server {
     server_name domain www.domain; 
     location / {
         include proxy_params; 
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want flask to be open to a port instead of a file you should override 
`[service]` to

```
[service]
...
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 -m 007 wsgi:app
```

And change your `nginx` config to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;`

This way you can have access to `port 8000` for checking how are working `gunicorn` and `flask`. Remember to be careful with firewall rules to secure `port 8000`. For a good discussion on which one is better you can try: [gunicorn + nginx: Server via socket or proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916016/gunicorn-nginx-server-via-socket-or-proxy)

Comment: Nginx is still trying to handle it and giving me a not found. Is this the right configuration?

I added the code in the original post.

Comment: Do you have a `handler` for `/` in your `flask` code?. The only thing that is giving you this new configuration is the ability to test `flask` without thinking on `nginx`

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do but I think nginx is interfering it somehow because when I do something like `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` in the server it just returns a not found from nginx.

Comment: and the ports are properly open.

Comment: Could you stop `nginx` for a while while you tests your `gunicorn/flask`?

Comment: Finally got it to work. You were right about leaving checking gunicorn first.